# Is "double positive meaning negative" a common phenomenon?

Tags: semantics, pragmatics, negation

The following joke is popular:

> An MIT linguistics professor was lecturing his class the other day. “In English,” he said, “a double negative forms a positive. However, in some languages, such as Russian, a double negative remains a negative. But there isn’t a single language, not one, in which a double positive can express a negative.”
>
> A voice from the back of the room piped up, “Yeah, right.”

But I wonder how common is the phenomenon. "yeah, right" isn't exactly double-positive, or at least it relies on intonation to convey the negative meaning. However, in Bulgarian "да, да" ("da, da" = "yes, yes") almost always means "no" (still, intonation plays a role).

What other languages exhibit this phenomenon?

Romanian also exhibits this feature. "Da, da", said in a certain way means "in no way" or "never".

Comment: Thats supposed to have been [Sidney Morgenbesser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidney_Morgenbesser).

Comment: The version I always heard has the voice in the back of the room saying "Yeah yeah".

Comment: Also note that "nope, wrong" isn't a double negative, nor is "no, no", so the examples of "yeah, right" and "yes, yes" are not analogous syntactically to what we call "double negatives".

Comment: One reason why I've never believed in this story as real is that I can't imagine many linguistics professors spouting the nonsense that "In English, a double negative forms a positive".

Comment: @ColinFine I can't not disagree with that!

Comment: @Qwertie, yes, litotes is one partial exception, and there are occasional, highly-marked, instances of explicit negatives cancelling out. But as a general statement "In English, a double negative forms a positive" is hogwash. Your example ends up being somewhat ambiguous, because the context (a linguistics discussion group) and the possible litotes, militate against the obvious reading = "can't disagree".

Comment: @ColinFine: The obvious reading of "can't not disagree" is "can't disagree"?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: yes, because "can't not disagree" is such an unlikely thing to say (absent a special context which justifies the double negative) that the most likely interpretation is to assume the "not" is an error.

Comment: we need to see whether the Bulgarian example is a true example of two positives resulting in a negative. irony or sarcasm is different.

Comment: double neg need not be positive in english, it could still be negative.  it ain't nothing is an example.

Comment: Exactly my point, @giridhar. Every native English speaker understands "It ain't nothing" as meaning "It is nothing" (unless there is a particular context and strong prosodic indication, like "It's nothing." "No, it **ain't** nothing"). People who claim that "It ain't nothing" means "It's something" are using "means" to mean "I think it ought to mean".

Comment: Related: [What is the reason for the double negation found in some languages?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/15334/)

Comment: Besides the _ironic_ double positive, there is also the _polite_ positive that does not consent necessarily (_"yes that is a good idea"_). Or _"yes but/though"_. So I think double positives does not really is not a semantically disruptive operation like negation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, for example, it's the same in Italian "*sì, sì*" (= yes, yes), but it's ambiguous, it depends on **intonation** and not on the words themselves; this means that "double positive = negative" is wrong speaking about the words, but it works through other means. Changing intonation, that "sì, sì" can be absolutely positive as well. We also use a small variation in *written language* to substitute the intonation. We write "seh seh" or "se se"... More or less like the English slang variation "ye ye".

By the way, the "double positive" also works for French "*c'est ça oui*" or Spanish "*sí sí*", still, it's the intonation that plays an important role.

And going back to that... Intonation is a *suprasegmental prosodic feature*, along with *pitch*, *stress*, *rhythm* and they all belong to [Prosody](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosody_%28linguistics%29). (There might be other features but right now I don't remember them.)

The prosodic features of a "unity" in spoken language are called *suprasegmental* because they occur simultaneously to the utterance (segments). When you say words, forming a sentence, you include *rhythm*, *intonation*, *stress*, *pitch* and these two "categories" occur at the same time.

You don't utter words first and intonation later.

So, usually that's what makes that utterance have a *positive* or a *negative* meaning to the hearer.

Answer (score 17):

*Ja, ja* in Dutch and German can express disbelief too.

But I don't think *ja, ja, да, да, yeah yeah*, or *yeah, right* should really count; they do not express a double positive in the sense that one positive modifies the other, nor that both modify the same thing. They are just strong (because repeated) positives used **ironically**; they indicate disbelief—but is it an actual negation? You could use any locution to express a negative [illocution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illocution):

> Oh, I'm sure your grandmother won't be shocked if you announce that you're gay on Christmas Eve and kiss your girlfriend. She will no doubt be thrilled.

As an alternative, it is possible that *ja, ja* originates in a polite phrase that no-one believes any more (instead of a faded ironic phrase).

The fact that doubling a negative gives a positive is inherent in negations, because they invert whatever falls under their scope. Positives do not invert; they do not change what falls under their scope like that.

Then again, who is to say what counts? Depending on one's definition, it could be argued that there are two positives, and that the whole is negative. I suppose it is a trivial matter at any rate.

Answer (score 10):

There is a difference between semantics (literal or metaphorical meanings) of utterances and their pragmatics (the real world contextual implications).

Sarcasm (though possibly marked phonetically in English by change in prosody) is a phenomenon of pragmatics.

In English, two positives **never** make a negative, the ostensible semantic derivation is that it is emphasis by repetition or, with mathematical terminology, idempotent.

The surface meaning of 'yeah, right' or 'yeah, yeah' is assuredly positive. It is the situation that let's us see that the student is only implicitly contradicting the teacher.

As to other languages, I'm sure the same joke can be translated, but that doesn't make the utterance of two positives a negative there also. Your Bulgarian example may be a native ostensible definition for 'da, da', but it is not a well known phenomenon among the worlds languages (if truly at all) for it to be a true negative.

Answer (score 1):

It *was* Sidney Morgenbesser, and the linguist (actually, philosopher of language) he was responding to was J.L. Austin.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidney_Morgenbesser)

The importance of prosody to distinguish between literalness and sarcasm, which Alennano mentions, reminds me of my own bête noire: people who claim that "I could care less" is incorrect or nonsense.  Steven Pinker writes about this very clearly, and concludes that "anyone who can't hear the difference has a tin ear."

This is actually very common in English -- American English, anyway.  Think of the very common "TELL me about it!", which most definitely does not mean "tell me about it."  I've always wondered if "I could care less", "tell me about it", "yeah, yeah", and phrases like that reflect a certain influence of Yiddish on American English, but I don't know.

Comment: It was also Larry Horn, linguist at Yale.  Question is who got there first, or who documented the claim first. Though it is most widely attributed to Morgenbesser.